# SwiftUI reduce spacing of rows in a list to null

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to reduce the linespacing in a list to null.

My tries with reducing the padding did not work.
Setting ´.environment(.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)´ helped a lot.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var data : [String] = ["first","second","3rd","4th","5th","6th"]

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      List {
        ForEach(data, id: \.self)
        { item in
          Text("\(item)")
          .padding(0)
          //.frame(height: 60)
          .background(Color.yellow)
        }
        //.frame(height: 60)
        .padding(0)
        .background(Color.blue)
      }
      .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)
      .onAppear { UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none }
      .onDisappear { UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .singleLine }
    }
  }
}
```

Changing the ´separatorStyle´ to ´.none´ only removed the Line but left the space.
Is there an extra ´hidden´ view for the Lists row or for the Separator between the rows?
How can this be controlled?

Would be using `ScrollView` instead of a `List` a good solution?

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true)
        {
      //List {
        ForEach(data, id: \.self)
        { item in
          HStack{
          Text("\(item)")
            Spacer()
          }
```

Does it also work for a large dataset?

Comment: On last question - definitely no? on before last - maybe (no cache, no reuse, all content built at start). On initial - it needs to think...

Comment: I personally prefer ScrollView, especially on macOS. Asperi's answer could solve your trouble. Using ScrollView is much more flexible, but be prepare for lot of secondary troubles with gestures. I hope ListStyle will be more configurable in next release of SwiftUI (may be some public API will be available)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, actually no surprise - `.separatorStyle = .none` works correctly. I suppose you confused text background with cell background - they are changed by different modifiers. Please find below tested & worked code (Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2)

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var data : [String] = ["first","second","3rd","4th","5th","6th"]

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      List {
        ForEach(data, id: \.self)
        { item in
          Text("\(item)")
            .background(Color.yellow) // text background
            .listRowBackground(Color.blue) // cell background
        }
      }
      .onAppear { UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none }
      .onDisappear { UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .singleLine }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update:**

> it's not possible to avoid the blue space between the yellow Texts?

Technically yes, it is possible, however for demo it is used hardcoded values and it is not difficult to fit some, while to calculate this dynamically might be challenging... anyway, here it is

[image: demo2]

it needs combination of stack for compression, content padding for resistance, and environment for limit:

```
  List {
    ForEach(data, id: \.self)
    { item in
        HStack {                                 // << A
          Text("\(item)")
            .padding(.vertical, 2)               // << B
        }
        .listRowBackground(Color.blue)
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .frame(height: 12)                       // << C
    }
  }
  .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 12)    // << D
```

Comment: Nice! Do you have an idea how to solve the same on macOS?

Comment: Tnx - but it's not possible to avoid the blue space between the yellow Texts?

Comment: @mica, in short - it is possible, but... see update section in answer.

Comment: what about dynamic content (unknown row height)? i updated my answer to show why i prefer ScrollView ...

Answer (score 4):

I do it the easy (iOS) SwiftUI way:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<10){ item in
                Color.green
            }
            .listRowInsets( EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0) )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not the SwiftUI way. This requires import UIKit which is a small problem on non iOS devices (macOS)

Comment: @Tycho Pandelaar That's why I put iOS in brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce row spacing is really tricky, try

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data : [String] = ["first","second","3rd","4th","5th","6th"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                        Color.red.frame(height: 1)
                        Text("\(item)").font(.largeTitle)
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                    }.background(Color.green)
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
                    .padding(.bottom, -25)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It use ScrollView instead of List and negative padding.

[image]

I didn't find any solution based on List, we have to ask Apple to publish xxxxStyle protocols and underlying structures.

UPDATE

What about this negative padding value? For sure it depends on height of our row content and unfortunately on SwiftUI layout strategy. Lets try some more dynamic content! (we use zero padding to demostrate the problem to solve)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data : [CGFloat] = [20, 30, 40, 25, 15]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                        Color.red.frame(height: 1)
                        Text("\(item)").font(.system(size: item))
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                    }.background(Color.green)
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
                    //.padding(.bottom, -25)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Clearly the row spacing is not fixed value! We have to calculate it for every row separately.

Next code snippet demonstrate the basic idea. I used global dictionary (to store height and position of each row) and tried to avoid any high order functions and / or some advanced SwiftUI technic, so it is easy to see the strategy. The required paddings are calculated only once, in .onAppear closure

```
import SwiftUI

var _p:[Int:(CGFloat, CGFloat)] = [:]

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data : [CGFloat] = [20, 30, 40, 25, 15]
    @State var space: [CGFloat] = []

    func spc(item: CGFloat)->CGFloat {
        if let d = data.firstIndex(of: item) {
            return d < space.count ? space[d] : 0
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                        Color.red.frame(height: 1)
                        Text("\(item)")
                            .font(.system(size: item))
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                    }
                    .background(
                        GeometryReader { proxy->Color in
                            if let i = self.data.firstIndex(of: item) {
                                _p[i] = (proxy.size.height, proxy.frame(in: .global).minY)
                            }
                            return Color.green
                        }
                    )
                    .padding(.leading, 5)
                    .padding(.bottom, -self.spc(item: item))

                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }.onAppear {
                    var arr:[CGFloat] = []
                    _p.keys.sorted(by: <).forEach { (i) in
                        let diff = (_p[i + 1]?.1 ?? 0) - (_p[i]?.1 ?? 0) - (_p[i]?.0 ?? 0)
                        if diff < 0 {
                            arr.append(0)
                        } else {
                            arr.append(diff)
                        }
                    }
                    self.space = arr
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running the code I've got

[image]

Comment: thx: do you see the sam problems as @Asperi with big datasets (no cache, no reuse, all content built at start)?

Comment: @mica in the snippet you can see an idea, ForEach is there to build dynamic content  on demand, i don't see any difference ... the most trouble is to implement the same gestures as list row has by default. Finally, ScrollView solution is usable even on macOS. You have to decide ... nothing is for free!

Comment: @mica see the update with different example where the row content is more dynamic